# How to solve TypeError: create() got an unexpected keyword argument in create function of my view in DRF

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-rest-viewsets

I am faced with the problem that **I can not successfully receive the kwarg's related with the id of my model `Station` and as a result I can not create my record through my view in the create function.**

Despite the fact that I can receive the kwarg's in the `get_queryset` function , this is not possible in `create` function.

If I keep the create function only in my serializer I can create the record successfully, but instead I want to add logic and return the created record from the view to serializer and not directly create the record from serializer.

Here is my snippets:

url

```
path('availability/<uuid:station_id>/', StationAvailabilityList.as_view(),name = 'station_availability_list'),
```

view

```
class StationAvailabilityList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = StationAvailabilitySerializer
    permission_classes = [IsChargingStationOwnerWithStation | IsReadOnlyStations]

    def get_queryset(self):
        station_owner = self.request.user
        station_id = self.kwargs['station_id']
        station = Station.objects.get(id = station_id)
        availabilities = StationAvailability.objects.filter(station = station)
        return availabilities


    def create(self, request):
        station_id = self.kwargs['station_id']
        availability_data = request.data
        return super().create(request)
```

The `get_queryset()` works fine, i can get the id of the Station record given in the url, but in the create I get the error :

```
TypeError: create() got an unexpected keyword argument 'station_id'
```

Here is the full traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/stations/availability/db2059a0-008a-4689-88ca-a1c5bde5a1af/



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/giorgos/.local/share/virtualenvs/ev-loader-backend-tcqKXHeF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/giorgos/.local/share/virtualenvs/ev-loader-backend-tcqKXHeF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/giorgos/.local/share/virtualenvs/ev-loader-backend-tcqKXHeF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/giorgos/.local/share/virtualenvs/ev-loader-backend-tcqKXHeF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/giorgos/.local/share/virtualenvs/ev-loader-backend-tcqKXHeF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/giorgos/.local/share/virtualenvs/ev-loader-backend-tcqKXHeF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/giorgos/.local/share/virtualenvs/ev-loader-backend-tcqKXHeF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/giorgos/.local/share/virtualenvs/ev-loader-backend-tcqKXHeF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/giorgos/.local/share/virtualenvs/ev-loader-backend-tcqKXHeF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 502, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/giorgos/.local/share/virtualenvs/ev-loader-backend-tcqKXHeF/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 242, in post
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /api/stations/availability/db2059a0-008a-4689-88ca-a1c5bde5a1af/
Exception Value: create() got an unexpected keyword argument 'station_id'
```

serializer/ create function:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        print(validated_data)
        station_data = validated_data.pop('station')
        validated_data_station_id = station_data.pop('id')
        station_id = uuid.UUID(validated_data_station_id)
        station = Station.objects.get(id=station_id)
        station_availability = StationAvailability.objects.create(station=station,**validated_data)
        return station_availability
```

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def create(self, request, **kwargs):
    station_id = kwargs['station_id']
    availability_data = request.data
    return super().create(request)
```

Comment: It works, thanks. I am wondering why I can not take the station_id by calling self.kwargs['station_id']. In similar create functions i got the kwarg's value like this i mentioned. Anyway.